# JS в PHP, получение через VK.API пользователей группы, execute

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Есть следующий код на Javascript, который с помощью метода `execute` VK.API получает по 25 тысяч пользователей группы за один запрос. Прошу помочь переделать его в хранимую процедуру приложения ВК + PHP.

```
VK.init({
    apiId: 654647 // ID вашего приложения VK
});

var membersGroups = []; // массив участников группы
getMembers(20629724);

// получаем информацию о группе и её участников
function getMembers(group_id) {
    VK.Api.call('groups.getById', {group_id: group_id, fields: 'photo_50,members_count', v: '5.27'}, function(r) {
            if(r.response) {
                $('.group_info')
                .html('<img src="' + r.response[0].photo_50 + '"/><br/>' 
                    + r.response[0].name
                    + '<br/>Участников: ' + r.response[0].members_count);
                getMembers20k(group_id, r.response[0].members_count); // получем участников группы и пишем в массив membersGroups
            }
    });
}

// получаем участников группы, members_count - количество участников
function getMembers20k(group_id, members_count) {
    var code =  'var members = API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": ' + group_id + ', "v": "5.27", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "1000", "offset": ' + membersGroups.length + '}).items;' // делаем первый запрос и создаем массив
            +   'var offset = 1000;' // это сдвиг по участникам группы
            +   'while (offset < 25000 && (offset + ' + membersGroups.length + ') < ' + members_count + ')' // пока не получили 20000 и не прошлись по всем участникам
            +   '{'
                +   'members = members + "," + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": ' + group_id + ', "v": "5.27", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "1000", "offset": (' + membersGroups.length + ' + offset)}).items;' // сдвиг участников на offset + мощность массива
                +   'offset = offset + 1000;' // увеличиваем сдвиг на 1000
            +   '};'
            +   'return members;'; // вернуть массив members

    VK.Api.call("execute", {code: code}, function(data) {
        if (data.response) {
            membersGroups = membersGroups.concat(JSON.parse("[" + data.response + "]")); // запишем это в массив
            $('.member_ids').html('Загрузка: ' + membersGroups.length + '/' + members_count);
            if (members_count >  membersGroups.length) // если еще не всех участников получили
                setTimeout(function() { getMembers20k(group_id, members_count); }, 333); // задержка 0.333 с. после чего запустим еще раз
            else // если конец то
                alert('Ура тест закончен! В массиве membersGroups теперь ' + membersGroups.length + ' элементов.');
        } else {
            alert(data.error.error_msg); // в случае ошибки выведем её
        }
    });
}
```

В моём PHP коде сам запрос к API VK (синтаксис/интерфейс доступа к API VK) выглядит, к примеру, так:

```
    $group_members2 = $vk->api('groups.getMembers', array(
                    'group_id'  => $groupID,
                    'count'     => '1000',
                    'offset'    => $offset,
                ));
```

Comment: вас цикл `while(...) { }` интересует? Код php у вас есть, записи получает, т.е. вам осталось только в цикл это обернуть. Я что-то упустил?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы `$vk->api` запрос был не `groups.getMembers`, а `execute`. То есть я не понимаю, как вытащить из JS VKScript, сделать его хранимой процедурой и вызывать её из PHP.

Comment: ну так в `execute` в `code` вы передаете не js-скрипт, а VKScript, т.е. его и надо передать в php-коде без изменений. Хотя зачем вам это надо, если то же самое вы можете сами сделать и без `execute`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно чтобы ваш метод отсылал формировал урл в таком виде:
`https://api.vk.com/method/execute.ИМЯ_ПРОЦЕДУРЫ?СПИСОК_ПАРАМЕТРОВ`

к примеру:

`https://api.vk.com/method/execute.mymethod?group_id=1&count=1000&offset=100`

Переданные параметры будут доступны внутри кода процедуры в виде полей объекта Args, например, если Вы передали ?user=123, то значение этой переменной будет доступно в Args.user

Следовательно, у себя в настройках приложения в хранимых процедурах пишите метод по имени mymethod

`return API.groups.getMembers({group_id: Args.group_id, count: Args.count, offset: Args.offset});`

Предположу, что класс по работе с апи php, взят отсюда:
[VKAPI](https://github.com/vladkens/VK/blob/master/src/VK/VK.php)

И метод "api" позволяет формировать запрос типа "execute"

Answer (score 1):

Я [**вот тут**](https://toster.ru/q/417801) писал про это.

```
class DevClass {
  public $group_id = 30666517;
  public $membersGroups = array();
  public $access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public function devMethod(){
    $opts = ["group_id"=>$this->group_id, "access_token"=>$this->access_token, "fields"=>"photo_50,members_count", "v"=>"5.80"];
    $answer = $this->vk->getMethod("groups.getById", $opts, true);
    //$members_count = $answer->response[0]->members_count;
    $members_count = 45000;
    $members_groups = 0;    //изначально в массиве 0 объектов
    //выполняем цикл пока полученное кол-во участников меньше общего кол-ва участников в группе
    while($members_count > $members_groups){
      usleep(300000);   //задержка на 0.3 сек.
      $answer = $this->getMembers25k($this->group_id, $members_count);
      if($answer->response){
        $new = explode(",",$answer->response);
        $this->membersGroups = array_merge($this->membersGroups, $new);
        //второй раз определяем переменную, уже с новым массивом данных
        $members_groups = count($this->membersGroups);
      }
      else{
        echo "NO RESPONSE";
                print_r($answer);
        die();
      }
    }
    print_r($this->membersGroups);
    die();
  }

  public function getMembers25k($group_id, $members_count) {
    $members_groups = count($this->membersGroups);
    $offset = 1000;
    $code =  'var members = API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": '.$this->group_id.', "v": "5.80", "sort": "id_asc", "count": '.$offset.', "offset": '.$members_groups.'}).items;'
      .'var offset = '.$offset.';'
      .'while (offset < 25000 && (offset + '.$members_groups.') < '.$members_count.')'
      .'{members = members + "," + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": '.$this->group_id.', "v": "5.80", "sort": "id_asc", "count": '.$offset.', "offset": ('.$members_groups.' + offset)}).items;offset = offset + '.$offset.';};'
      .'return members;';

    $answer = $this->vk->getMethod("execute", ["code" => urlencode($code), "v"=>"5.80", "access_token" => $this->access_token], true);
        return $answer;
  }
}

$dev = new DevClass();
$dev->devMethod();
```

Но надо понимать, что тут у меня уже сформирован `access_token` другим классом, как и запросы к методам (`$this`-> `vk` -> `getMethod`); я лишь хотел показать логику.